# How to separate a PDO named placeholder from rest of a string

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a PDO prepared statement which looks like this:

```
$STH = $DBH->("CREATE TABLE :prefixbase (table_structure)");
```

:prefix should be replaced with `userprefix_`. The resulting SQL should look like this: `CREATE TABLE userprefix_base(table structure)`. How can I separate the placeholder from the rest of the string?

Comment: PDO doesn't support prepared statements for dynamic table nor for field names, so what you want to do is probably impossible to do properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need to use regular expression or simple find-replace on your string, which after such processing can be used by PDO object as a proper SQL command.

Here is an example:

```
$subject = "CREATE TABLE :prefixbase(table_structure)";

$sql = preg_replace('/(:prefix)/', 'userprefix_', $subject);
// or
$sql = str_replace(':prefix', 'userprefix_', $subject);
```

P.S. I hope I understood your request correctly.

Comment: You got it right. Chose this as answer, because I personally think it's cleaner solution than the on DanMan posted. Just an other question, If I get the `'userprefix_'` from a client input, I have to sanitize it against SQL-injection, besaus it is not protected by the PDO statement any more. Or am I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @wowpatrick Yes, you need to sanitize it, you need to do it in any case as it is a user input. Although it is quite unlikely at this stage (project setup) that someone will be messing around it better not to take any chances (you never know who will have access to setup files). To sanitize table prefix you need to remove all characters that are not letters, digits or underscore.

Comment: Just don't use regular expressions, if you don't absolutely need them. They're always slower than a simple replacement.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$placeholder="userprefix_";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("CREATE TABLE ".$placeholder."base (table_structure)");
```

Unless that prefix is supposed to change after having prepared the statement. That wouldn't work without preparing another statement.

Comment: 1+: Also works just as fine as the solution LazyOne posted, but as said, I personally prefere his answer.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. IMO it's better to avoid function invocations if possible, but YMMV.